# How to pull comments from individual Youtube videos instead of random videos

Tags: python, pandas, youtube-data-api

I'm building a project using the Youtube API where I want to pull comments from each video in a specific youtuber's channel. However, when I pull the comments, it only pulls one comment from each video instead of pulling 100 comments from each video like I want it to.

```
def get_video_comments(video_id):
    url_video_comments ='https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId='+video_id+'&maxResults=100&key='+API_KEY
    response_video_comments = requests.get(url_video_comments).json()
    
    for comment in response_video_comments['items']:
        if comment['kind'] == 'youtube#commentThread':
            comment_text = comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal']
            comment_likes = comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['likeCount']
    
    return comment_text, comment_likes

def get_videos(df,df_comments,pageToken):
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='+API_KEY+'&channelId='+channel_id+'&pageToken='+pageToken+'&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=10000'
    
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    # wait 1 second before executing for loop in order to get all of the data
    time.sleep(1)
    # create loop to get information on every video
    for video in response['items']:
        # makes sure that we only get information on videos
        if video['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':
            video_id = video['id']['videoId']
            video_title = video['snippet']['title']
            upload_date = video['snippet']['publishedAt']
            upload_date = str(upload_date).split('T')[0]

            view_count, like_count, comment_count = get_video_details(video_id)
            comment_text, comment_likes = get_video_comments(video_id)
            # save data in pandas DF
            df = df.append({'video_id':video_id,'video_title':video_title, 'upload_date':upload_date, 'view_count':view_count,
                            'like_count':like_count,'comment_count':comment_count}
                          , ignore_index=True)
            df_comments = df_comments.append({'video_id':video_id, 'comment_text':comment_text,
                                             'comment_likes':comment_likes},ignore_index=True)
    return df, df_comments
```

Below is the output.

```
    video_id    comment_text    comment_likes
0   0faCad2kKeg Basically, this video describes how you are ab...   0
1   9dnN82DsQ2k thanks for using metric 0
2   Y413Czri6qw "Another way to fight climate change is to eat...   0
3   W3qZIPiWKc4 6:00    0
4   ggUduBmvQ_4 should be illegal to pull loans for speculation 0
5   xhxo2oXRiio Man, this is really getting to me :(    0
6   8d5d_HXGeMA Not sure how you can fail to bring up powerful...   0
7   8egszLpKMWU africa is not the next anything.    0
8   WNrobOYWZQE For space exploration to happen, war needs to ...   0
9   ZZ3F3zWiEmc Taxes themselves are Legalized theft. Moreover...   0
10  V16GdzRvhRU Saudi Arabia and the other Islamic oil kingdom...   0
11  o4tuhWvKduU This video makes getting out of Afganistan see...   0
12  1-uNMj57Y4c Meanwhile, I am not in the air travel market a...   0
13  SR7BA3xEmDo rather trains...... 0
14  iO5mfbpq16A Because the Southern hemisphere is mostly wate...   0
15  B3FKtBNEBRc The annoying playground cytomorphologically sm...   0
16  VJtFgte1GKc 10:36 the ruthless pursuit of a fish in sea 0
17  J5PLyYVIEpg "Indian nation" Indians are in India    1
18  LHhJuAOK3CI This is really great, but I hope you do more p...   0
19  aH4b3sAs-l8 What would happen if lightning hit it mid flight?   0
20  b1JlYZQG3lI You actually can't be more wrong. We shut down...   1
21  BNpk_OGEGlA We control the supply chain by how involved we...   0
22  4p0fRlCHYyg Hey did you see the “new” united supersonic pl...   0
23  N4dOCfWlgBw I hope the cruise industry dies 0
24  3CuPqeIJr3U You westerners your days are up..Just get lost  0
25  DlTq8DbRs4k Maggie's dead now :)    0
26  VjiH3mpxyrQ What you’ve missed about ‘Crisis’ stress testi...   0
27  pLcqJ2DclEg If I were to buy a Tesla Today, I would also h...   0
28  3gdCH1XUIlE I’m glad I live in a civilized country where t...   0
29  2qanMpnYsjk I just had this recommended to me and I can al...   0
30  7R7jNWHp0D0 Another unequal biased Biden loving Trump hat...    0
31  GIFV_Z7Y9_w Hello from Kazakhstan   0
32  KXRtNwUju5g This is sexist, why was it women that throws t...   0
33  fTyUE162lrw What's the point of these subscription based l...   0
34  ZAEydOjNWyQ So if Covid is stoping it, just get everybody ...   0
35  _BCY0SPOFpE Great observation   0
36  v_rXhuaI0W8 13:50 Such a lie. 1) The two have nothing to d...   0
37  Ongqf93rAcM This works but it’s still gambling so don’t ex...   0
38  byW1GExQB84 Can we have an update?\nAstra Zeneca seems rea...   1
39  DTIDCA7mjZs My dad be like: Gracias por las instrucciones ...   1
40  H_akzwzghWQ Why are you showing us graphs of "percent devi...   0
41  7C1fPocIFgU There is a (partial) solution in the middle. C...   0
42  3J06af5xHD0 Her speech bought me to tears.  0
43  YgiMqePRp0Y There is a problem with pooled testing. The th...   0
44  Rtmhv5qEBg0 Great work good game    0
45  6GMoUmvw8kU 9:48 yo, wtf is wrong with that man`s face? 0
46  QlPrAKtegFQ Follow along as a west bound autonomous 80,000...   0
47  uAG4zCsiA_w development of tiltrotor aircraft has almost s...   1
48  NtX-Ibi21tU Wait there is a risk of 1:55 000 by walking ou...   0
49  r2oPk20OHBE 2:41 The street where I live was the last thin...   0
```

The video_id matches the video that I want to pull the comments from. I'm just struggling to understand how I can pull more than one comment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `get_video_comments` function is quite well designed with the for loop `for comment in response_video_comments['items']:` however at each iteration you overwrite the previous comment that was in `comment_text` your `get_video_comments` function should instead returns an array of `comment_text` and `comment_likes` and at each iteration you should happend to this array the current working `comment`.

The algorithm to grab all comments from a video is very common, deepen your searches if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thank you so much! I created 2 arrays like you suggested and it worked!